# How to fix the error "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. "

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have trained two simple CNN models to recognize license number and transfer them into two functions: predict_provinces.py and predict_digits.py. They can run individually and return the true number. However, when they run together, the error appear as "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. "

I have tried to use the argument

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(SAVER_DIR, 'model.ckpt.meta'),clear_devices=True), but it doesn't help.
```

predict_provinces.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import PlateNumberRecognition.config as config
import cv2
import numpy as np

NUM_CLASSES = config.DIGITS_NUM_CLASSES
SAVER_DIR = config.DIGITS_SAVER_DIR
HEIGHT = config.HEIGHT
WIDTH = config.WIDTH
CHANNEL_NUM = config.CHANNEL_NUM
LETTERS_DIGITS=config.LETTERS_DIGITS
def digit_predict(digit_arr):
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(SAVER_DIR, 'model.ckpt.meta'))
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNEL_NUM])
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        model_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(SAVER_DIR)
        saver.restore(sess, model_file)
        conv1_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer1-conv1/weight:0')
        conv1_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer1-conv1/bias:0')
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv1_w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        relu1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, conv1_b))
        pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


        conv2_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer3-conv2/weight:0')
        conv2_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer3-conv2/bias:0')
        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, conv2_w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        relu2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, conv2_b))
        pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


        fc1_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer5-fc1/weight:0')
        fc1_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer5-fc1/bias:0')
        pool_shape = pool2.get_shape().as_list()
        nodes = pool_shape[1] * pool_shape[2] * pool_shape[3]

        reshaped = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, nodes])
        fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshaped, fc1_w) + fc1_b)

        fc2_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer6-fc2/weight:0')
        fc2_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer6-fc2/bias:0')

        result = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(fc1, fc2_w) + fc2_b)

        _, binary = cv2.threshold(digit_arr, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        # print(binary.shape)
        # cv2.imshow('window1', binary)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)
        for i in range(binary.shape[0]):
            for j in range(binary.shape[1]):
                if binary[i][j]==0:
                    binary[i][j]=1
                else:
                    binary[i][j]=0
        img_data = np.reshape(binary,[1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNEL_NUM])
        result = sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: np.array(img_data)})

        max = 0
        max_index = 0

        for j in range(NUM_CLASSES):
            if result[0][j] > max:
                max = result[0][j]
                max_index = j
                continue
    return config.LETTERS_DIGITS[max_index]
```

predict_digits.py

```
predict_provinces.py
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import PlateNumberRecognition.config as config
import numpy as np
import PlateNumberRecognition
NUM_CLASSES = config.PROVINCE_NUM_CLASSES
SAVER_DIR = config.PROVINCE_SAVER_DIR
HEIGHT = config.HEIGHT
WIDTH = config.WIDTH
CHANNEL_NUM = config.CHANNEL_NUM

SIZE = config.SIZE
PROVINCES = config.PROVINCES

def predict_provinces(pro_arr):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNEL_NUM])
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(SAVER_DIR, 'model.ckpt.meta'),clear_devices=True)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        model_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(SAVER_DIR)
        saver.restore(sess, model_file)
        conv1_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer1-conv1/weight:0')
        conv1_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer1-conv1/bias:0')

        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv1_w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        relu1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, conv1_b))
        pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


        conv2_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer3-conv2/weight:0')
        conv2_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer3-conv2/bias:0')
        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, conv2_w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        relu2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, conv2_b))
        pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


        fc1_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer5-fc1/weight:0')
        fc1_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer5-fc1/bias:0')
        pool_shape = pool2.get_shape().as_list()
        nodes = pool_shape[1] * pool_shape[2] * pool_shape[3]

        reshaped = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, nodes])
        fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshaped, fc1_w) + fc1_b)

        fc2_w = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer6-fc2/weight:0')
        fc2_b = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer6-fc2/bias:0')

        result = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(fc1, fc2_w) + fc2_b)

        img_data = np.reshape(pro_arr, [1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNEL_NUM])
        result = sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: np.array(img_data)})

        max = 0
        max_index = 0

        for j in range(NUM_CLASSES):
            if result[0][j] > max:
                max = result[0][j]
                max_index = j
                continue
        license_number = PROVINCES[max_index]
    return license_number
```

test.py

```
import PlateNumberRecognition.predict_digits as pd
import PlateNumberRecognition.predict_provinces as pp
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
pic_1=cv2.imread('6.bmp',0)
pic_2=cv2.imread('1.bmp',0)
pp.predict_provinces(pic_2)
pd.digit_predict(pic_1)
```

the error

```
G:\Pycharm\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/asus/Desktop/Intelligent-Transportation/PlateNumberRecognition/test.py
2019-03-19 17:21:24.765040: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Pycharm\test\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "G:\Pycharm\test\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "G:\Pycharm\test\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [512,6] rhs shape= [512,34]
```

I expect to use these two functions together

Comment: Please share code of `test.py`

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have uploaded test.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solve the problem by using two graph to run the two functions respectively.
Changed test.py is as follow:

```
import PlateNumberRecognition.predict_digits as pd
import PlateNumberRecognition.predict_provinces as pp
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
pic_1=cv2.imread('6.bmp',0)
pic_2=cv2.imread('1.bmp',0)
g1=tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default():
    pp.predict_provinces(pic_2)
g2=tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default():
    pd.digit_predict(pic_1)
```

However, I don’t know why it can fix this problem...